# Curve Fitting (Two Exponentials and Gaussian Function)

Tags: curves, mathematical-modeling

I have the following equation fit to my data
[sum of two exponential functions and Gaussian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzoqD.png)

It appears like this [Raw data with curve fit overlayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18Yfu.png)
I achieved this using non linear regression

How can I obtain the standard deviation for the exponential curves (together) and the Gaussian function?

Comment: Have you have been able to fit $(h_1,x_0,w_1,h_2,w_2,h_p,c_p,w_p)$ ?  Which software did you use for it ?

Comment: Yes, I was able to fit it as shown in the second image. I used nls() function in R; nonlinear least squares function. I obtained those parameters.

Comment: Impressive, for sure !

Comment: Hmm..perhaps but I would like to extract more information from the fitted curves such as a measure of variability etc. Right now only cp gives the "peak diameter" of the Gaussian function.